# Wordpress Url redirect

Tags: mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a big problem with a Wordpress project, I just downloaded a Wordpress project with it's Mysql contents.

I want to run it in my localhost, All sets up, but when i launch the url in my localhost it goes to another url.

I edited some parameters here :

wp-config.php : 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE'

and from Mysql i edited "siteurl" & "home" from wp_options table.
I also edit RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} = from .htaccess

So it doesn't redirect to url but Wordpress not launch. without any error!! it seems you enter wrong url in your browser.

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information. What is in the .htaccess? Where do you get redirected to? What do you mean by "All sets up"?

Comment: turn on the wordpress debug option:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

 - which webserver do you use?

Comment: @BlueEel Xampp on mac osx

Comment: @BlueEel This is a Wordpress installed on example.com when i run it on my localhost it redirect to example.com again. All sets up mean i setup every thing correctly, wordpress connected to localhost with mysql

Comment: Does Apaches error.log tell you anything?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `wp-config.php` has these settings:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost' );
define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://localhost');
```

By default wordpress will redirect you to what's defined by `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE`, and if you've gone somewhere else, the `NOBLOGREDIRECT` will redirect you back to localhost.

Comment: as i mentioned, i'm sure about that

Answer (score 0):

not to sure if you have tried to export whole site ie tools > export in admin panel. [check this page](http://www.premiumwebbloghosting.com/2012/07/moving-wordpress-from-hosting-to-localhost.html).

Good Luck